# How can I make a nested if statement work properly?

Tags: python

when joinedarea triggers, instead of output that "person joined area!" it loops back up to the if statement where it's checking if trade is none. I'm trying to nest it within the elif statement but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the syntax.

```py
def tradescan(d):
    logfile = open("log.txt","r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        trade = re.match("([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*\\[INFO Client [0-9]*] @(To|From) (?:<(.+)> )?([a-zA-Z_, ]+): (.+)", line)
        joinedarea = re.match("([0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*\\[INFO Client [0-9]*] : (\\S+) has joined the area\\.", line)
        #print(joinedarea[2])
        incoming = "From"
        if trade is None:
            print("Scanning game for appropriate trades...")
        elif (trade[2] == incoming):
            user = trade[4]
            splitat = 25
            r = trade[5][splitat:]
            split = r.split()
            int_list = re.findall("[0-9]+", r)
            try:
                price1 = int_list[0]
            except IndexError:
                print("Trade Mismatch - ignoring trade from", user)
                continue

            try:
                price2 = int_list[1]
            except IndexError:
                print("Trade Mismatch - ignoring trade from", user)
                continue

            #print(price1, price2)
            matches = {x for x in d if x in r}
            items = list(matches)
            try:
                iname1 = items[0]
            except IndexError:
                print("Trade Mismatch - ignoring trade from", user)
                continue

            try:
                iname2 = items[1]
            except IndexError:
                print("Trade Mismatch - ignoring trade from", user)
                continue

            print(Fore.YELLOW + Back.MAGENTA + Style.BRIGHT + user, "wants", price1, iname1, "for", price2, iname2 + Style.RESET_ALL),
            py.moveTo(567, 26, 2)
            py.click()
            py.typewrite(['enter'])
            py.typewrite('/invite ' + user + '\n')
            try:
                userjoin = joinedarea[2]
            except TypeError:
                print("Waiting for", user, "to join area...")
                continue
            if joinedarea:
                print(userjoin, "joined area!")
```

Comment: How do you verify that `joinedarea` actually triggered?

Comment: This means that `joinedarea` is not triggered at all

Comment: If i move it outside of the elif it processes fine based on the log file being updated but the actions it will take will rely on variable data within the elif. I'm honestly not sure where I'm going wrong.